# Best practices composer and Symfony bundle

Tags: symfony, namespaces, composer-php

I starting a bundle with symfony 3.2. It works find in the src directory not in vendor directory. before to go forward. I decided to publish it in packagist/ Github. So i did composer.json and apprently i did something wrong because when i install it the namespace generate an error and if i check in composer autoload nothing about my package. I you have an idea thank for your help.
The pakacge is https://github.com/fabgg/jukeboxBundle

Comment: Do you want to install symfony2 Setup using Composer.?

Answer (score 1):

First Download Composer. https://getcomposer.org/download/

Then Open Command Prompt. go to htdocs directory and Run the Command

```
composer require symfony/finder
```

Refer : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/using_components.html

Comment: I already have this package. my error is when appKernel loading. Attempted to load class "FabggJukeboxBundle" from namespace "Fabgg\JukeboxBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Fabgg\JukeboxBundle\FabggJukeboxBundle" 
I chek my composer.json with command validate  it seems ok.